# Have comic villains protected themselves from the kind of attack shown in What If..? episode 3?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, comics, ant-man, marvel-what-if-2021

In Marvel's *What If..?* episode 3 we see that

> Hank Pym, as Yellowjacket, is on a revenge mission against S.H.I.E.L.D. because Hope has died. Hank is murdering the future Avengers one by one, and even manages to make the Hulk explode by entering his bloodstream and shooting a resizer disk into his heart. Doesn't this prove the Ant-Man-entering-Thanos'-rectum theory plausible, meaning that in the main Marvel Cinematic Universe, future enemies could be defeated by Scott Lang employing similar tactics?

Are there any comic examples of Ant-Man entering an enemy's body in order to defeat them? And if so, has any villain ever prevented this in some way?

I found a comic cover where he is inside a bloodstream. Though I don't know why, he definitely has been inside someone before.

> Ant-Man 2015 #5
> [image: Ant-Man 2015 #5 cover art]

Comment: There's no indication Scott ever became Ant-Man in that universe. In fact, given what we saw happen, he probably didn't. We don't even know if this universe will feature again at the moment. I'm not really sure what your question is either to be honest.

Comment: I didn't ask specifically for that world. Presumably Ant-man of Earth 616 could do all those things, no? My question is has there been comic examples of him trying to defeat someone via the same method in the episode, but been prevented from doing so.

Comment: Could but would he think of it? Also killing people like that isn't exactly the sort of things heroes do.

Comment: If you're asking solely of this happening in the comics and it being prevented you probably want to remove the other questions as well then and focus it properly.

Comment: Scott's a pretty cunning guy, I don't think it takes a genius to realize you can do that. And if a villian is going to kill his daughter who wouldn't kill that person? Only the one question is presumed. I'm asking if Kang has been shown or any other villian shown to stop it. But sure.

Comment: It's worth noting that The Hulk was initially hit while still human and thus vulnerable, and in a non-fatal way that made it take a bit longer to transform. In comparison, Thanos is pretty much "armored" at all times with his superior physiology.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots But literally no armor or physiology would matter to Scott's Ant-man since he reached quantum level. That's why I'm asking the question isn't Ant-man now really really OP?

Comment: Not necessarily. A lot of it depends on whether or not he can expand himself enough to "throw" a disc and get out. In Bruce's case, he was basically able to get to empty space and expand before throwing the disk, shrinking down, and leaving. 
The rules for when Ant-Man can expand aren't entirely fleshed out. For all we know, it might have squished him to try expanding somewhere other than inside a regular human's chest cavity.

Comment: Note that Loki fully blanks the same attack in said episode

Comment: @RogueJedi yes, because he was aware of him trying to do so. Everyone else was unaware, and one of Ant-man's best traits is his ability to go undetected. Like if Vision knew Ant-Man was trying to stop him, he would simply phase. That's why I asked for possible comic references of this.

Comment: "if a villian is going to kill his daughter who wouldn't kill that person?" — As Dumbledore said in *Lord of the Rings*, "We don't trade lives".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hank Pym (as Hank Pym the Scientific Adventurer) once shrank Wonder Man down so that he could go inside a (fake) Ultron and then return to normal size, destroying the Ultron.  This was in an issue of West Coast Avengers back in the 1990s.

West Coast Avengers #42, Issue Date: March 1989, 'One of our Androids is Missing!'

Comment: West Coast Avengers #42, Issue Date: March 1989, 'One of our Androids is Missing!'